# Getting data from linux perf in real time

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

I'm working on an application which forks a bunch of child processes. I'm using linux perf to find the places where shared memory pages get modified and copied by child processes.

```
sudo perf probe --add do_wp_page
sudo perf record -e probe:do_wp_page -ag
```

When I'm done I can then use perf report etc to get results.

My question is whether there's a way to capture this recorded information in real time somehow, so I can show this in the application itself? The closest I can find is to use --switch-output to periodically dump recorded data to different files.